# What does the expression \X match when inside a RegEx?

Tags: regex, unicode

According to http://www.regular-expressions.info,

> You can consider `\X` the Unicode version of the dot in regex engines that use plain ASCII.

Does this mean that it will match *any* possible [Unicode](http://unicode.org/) code point?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The site's description is pretty good:

> \X    Matches a single Unicode grapheme, whether encoded as a single code point or multiple code points using combining marks. A grapheme most closely resembles the everyday concept of a "character".   \X matches à encoded as U+0061 U+0300, à encoded as U+00E0, ©, etc.

So, the thing that makes it Unicode-aware is that it can match *several code points* when those combine to a single visible "thing" (grapheme).

See [Wikipedia's page on Combining Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) for more detail, it lists the U+0300 codepoint mentioned above, for instance.

Answer (score 7):

From [Perl regex manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc):

> This matches a Unicode *extended grapheme cluster*.
>
> `\X` matches quite
>   well what normal (non-Unicode-programmer) usage would consider a
>   single character. As an example, consider a G with some sort of
>   diacritic mark, such as an arrow. There is no such single character in
>   Unicode, but one can be composed by using a G followed by a Unicode
>   "COMBINING UPWARDS ARROW BELOW", and would be displayed by
>   Unicode-aware software as if it were a single character.
>
> Mnemonic: eXtended Unicode character.

And from [PCRE man pages](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) (2012):

> PCRE implements a simpler version of \X than Perl, which changed  to make  \X  match what Unicode calls an "extended grapheme cluster".
>   This is more complicated than an extended Unicode sequence,  which  is
>   what PCRE matches.
>
> *[...]*
>
> \X       an extended Unicode sequence
>
> *[...]*
>
> The  \X  escape  matches  any number of Unicode characters that form an extended Unicode sequence. \X is equivalent to
>
> ```
> (?>\PM\pM*)
> ```
>
> That is, it matches a character without the "mark"  property, 
>   followed by  zero  or  more  characters with the "mark" property, and
>   treats the sequence as an atomic group (see below).  Characters  with 
>   the  "mark" property  are  typically  accents  that affect the
>   preceding character. None of them have codepoints less than 256, so in
>   8-bit non-UTF-8  mode \X matches any one character.
>
> Note that recent versions of Perl have changed \X to match what
>   Unicode calls an "extended grapheme cluster", which has a more
>   complicated definition.

Later version of [PCRE man pages](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) (2015):

> Extended grapheme clusters
>
> The `\X` escape matches any number of Unicode  characters  that  form 
>   an "extended grapheme cluster", and treats the sequence as an atomic
>   group (see below).  Up to and including release 8.31, PCRE  matched 
>   an  ear- lier, simpler definition that was equivalent to
>
> ```
> (?>\PM\pM*)
> ```
>
> That  is,  it matched a character without the "mark" property,
>   followed by zero or more characters with the "mark"  property. 
>   Characters  with the  "mark"  property are typically non-spacing
>   accents that affect the preceding character.
>
> This simple definition was extended in Unicode to include more 
>   compli- cated  kinds of composite character by giving each character a
>   grapheme breaking property, and creating rules  that  use  these 
>   properties  to define  the  boundaries  of  extended grapheme
>   clusters. In releases of PCRE later than 8.31, `\X` matches one of
>   these clusters.
>
> `\X` always matches at least one character. Then it  decides  whether 
>   to add additional characters according to the following rules for
>   ending a cluster:
>
> 1. End at the end of the subject string.
> 2. Do not end between CR and LF; otherwise end after any control  char- acter.
> 3. Do  not  break  Hangul (a Korean script) syllable sequences. Hangul characters are of five types: L, V, T, LV, and LVT. An L
>      character  may be  followed by an L, V, LV, or LVT character; an LV or
>      V character may be followed by a V or T character; an LVT or T
>      character may be follwed only by a T character.
> 4. Do not end before extending characters or spacing marks. Characters with the "mark" property always have  the  "extend" 
>      grapheme  breaking property.
> 5. Do not end after prepend characters.
> 6. Otherwise, end the cluster.