# How to wrap each emoji with space with regex while replacing multiple spaces with single space

Tags: python, regex

I'm having string like this:

> ❗foo-foo⚠   9-8 ‍♀foo♀

Return of this example should be like this (separate):

> ❗ foo-foo ⚠  9-8  ‍♀ foo ♀

```
regex_sws = re.compile(r"([A-zА-яёЁ0-9−\-‒–一—―─]+)([^A-zА-яёЁ0-9]+)([A-zА-яёЁ0-9−\-‒–一—―─]+)", re.MULTILINE)
```

but how to extract groups \1\2\3 ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups <- This. tl;dr: do `.match` or `.search` on your pattern with the search string to get Match object, then that object has `.groups()` that will get you all subgroups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current emoji standard (see [Emoji List, v13.1](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.1/emoji-test.txt)), there are 4590 emojis.

You need to use a [regex that matches each separate emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56626951/3832970) to `re.split` the string while keeping the emojis themselves, get rid of empty strings and join the resulting list with a single space:

```py
import re
emoji_rx = r"[#*0-9]\uFE0F?\u20E3|©\uFE0F?|[®\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA]\uFE0F?|[\u231A\u231B]|[\u2328\u23CF]\uFE0F?|[\u23E9-\u23EC]|[\u23ED-\u23EF]\uFE0F?|\u23F0|[\u23F1\u23F2]\uFE0F?|\u23F3|[\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB\u25FC]\uFE0F?|[\u25FD\u25FE]|[\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611]\uFE0F?|[\u2614\u2615]|\u2618\uFE0F?|\u261D[\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\u2648-\u2653]|[\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E]\uFE0F?|\u267F|\u2692\uFE0F?|\u2693|[\u2694-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0]\uFE0F?|\u26A1|\u26A7\uFE0F?|[\u26AA\u26AB]|[\u26B0\u26B1]\uFE0F?|[\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5]|\u26C8\uFE0F?|\u26CE|[\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3]\uFE0F?|\u26D4|\u26E9\uFE0F?|\u26EA|[\u26F0\u26F1]\uFE0F?|[\u26F2\u26F3]|\u26F4\uFE0F?|\u26F5|[\u26F7\u26F8]\uFE0F?|\u26F9(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\u26FA\u26FD]|\u2702\uFE0F?|\u2705|[\u2708\u2709]\uFE0F?|[\u270A\u270B][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\u270C\u270D][\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\u270F\uFE0F?|[\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721]\uFE0F?|\u2728|[\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747]\uFE0F?|[\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757]|\u2763\uFE0F?|\u2764(?:\u200D[\U0001F525\U0001FA79]|\uFE0F(?:\u200D[\U0001F525\U0001FA79])?)?|[\u2795-\u2797]|\u27A1\uFE0F?|[\u27B0\u27BF]|[\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07]\uFE0F?|[\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]|[\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F004\U0001F0CF]|[\U0001F170\U0001F171\U0001F17E\U0001F17F]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F18E\U0001F191-\U0001F19A]|\U0001F1E6[\U0001F1E8-\U0001F1EC\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F1\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F6-\U0001F1FA\U0001F1FC\U0001F1FD\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1E7[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E7\U0001F1E9-\U0001F1EF\U0001F1F1-\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F6-\U0001F1F9\U0001F1FB\U0001F1FC\U0001F1FE\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1E8[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E8\U0001F1E9\U0001F1EB-\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F0-\U0001F1F5\U0001F1F7\U0001F1FA-\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1E9[\U0001F1EA\U0001F1EC\U0001F1EF\U0001F1F0\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F4\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1EA[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E8\U0001F1EA\U0001F1EC\U0001F1ED\U0001F1F7-\U0001F1FA]|\U0001F1EB[\U0001F1EE-\U0001F1F0\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F7]|\U0001F1EC[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E7\U0001F1E9-\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F1-\U0001F1F3\U0001F1F5-\U0001F1FA\U0001F1FC\U0001F1FE]|\U0001F1ED[\U0001F1F0\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F3\U0001F1F7\U0001F1F9\U0001F1FA]|\U0001F1EE[\U0001F1E8-\U0001F1EA\U0001F1F1-\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F6-\U0001F1F9]|\U0001F1EF[\U0001F1EA\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F5]|\U0001F1F0[\U0001F1EA\U0001F1EC-\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F3\U0001F1F5\U0001F1F7\U0001F1FC\U0001F1FE\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1F1[\U0001F1E6-\U0001F1E8\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F0\U0001F1F7-\U0001F1FB\U0001F1FE]|\U0001F1F2[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E8-\U0001F1ED\U0001F1F0-\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1F3[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E8\U0001F1EA-\U0001F1EC\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F1\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F5\U0001F1F7\U0001F1FA\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F2|\U0001F1F5[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1EA-\U0001F1ED\U0001F1F0-\U0001F1F3\U0001F1F7-\U0001F1F9\U0001F1FC\U0001F1FE]|\U0001F1F6\U0001F1E6|\U0001F1F7[\U0001F1EA\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F8\U0001F1FA\U0001F1FC]|\U0001F1F8[\U0001F1E6-\U0001F1EA\U0001F1EC-\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F7-\U0001F1F9\U0001F1FB\U0001F1FD-\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1F9[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E8\U0001F1E9\U0001F1EB-\U0001F1ED\U0001F1EF-\U0001F1F4\U0001F1F7\U0001F1F9\U0001F1FB\U0001F1FC\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1FA[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1EC\U0001F1F2\U0001F1F3\U0001F1F8\U0001F1FE\U0001F1FF]|\U0001F1FB[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1E8\U0001F1EA\U0001F1EC\U0001F1EE\U0001F1F3\U0001F1FA]|\U0001F1FC[\U0001F1EB\U0001F1F8]|\U0001F1FD\U0001F1F0|\U0001F1FE[\U0001F1EA\U0001F1F9]|\U0001F1FF[\U0001F1E6\U0001F1F2\U0001F1FC]|\U0001F201|\U0001F202\uFE0F?|[\U0001F21A\U0001F22F\U0001F232-\U0001F236]|\U0001F237\uFE0F?|[\U0001F238-\U0001F23A\U0001F250\U0001F251\U0001F300-\U0001F320]|[\U0001F321\U0001F324-\U0001F32C]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F32D-\U0001F335]|\U0001F336\uFE0F?|[\U0001F337-\U0001F37C]|\U0001F37D\uFE0F?|[\U0001F37E-\U0001F384]|\U0001F385[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F386-\U0001F393]|[\U0001F396\U0001F397\U0001F399-\U0001F39B\U0001F39E\U0001F39F]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3A0-\U0001F3C1]|\U0001F3C2[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F3C3\U0001F3C4](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F3C5\U0001F3C6]|\U0001F3C7[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F3C8\U0001F3C9]|\U0001F3CA(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F3CB\U0001F3CC](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F3CD\U0001F3CE]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3CF-\U0001F3D3]|[\U0001F3D4-\U0001F3DF]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3E0-\U0001F3F0]|\U0001F3F3(?:\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\U0001F308)|\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\U0001F308))?)?|\U0001F3F4(?:\u200D\u2620\uFE0F?|\U000E0067\U000E0062(?:\U000E0065\U000E006E\U000E0067|\U000E0073\U000E0063\U000E0074|\U000E0077\U000E006C\U000E0073)\U000E007F)?|[\U0001F3F5\U0001F3F7]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3F8-\U0001F407]|\U0001F408(?:\u200D\u2B1B)?|[\U0001F409-\U0001F414]|\U0001F415(?:\u200D\U0001F9BA)?|[\U0001F416-\U0001F43A]|\U0001F43B(?:\u200D\u2744\uFE0F?)?|[\U0001F43C-\U0001F43E]|\U0001F43F\uFE0F?|\U0001F440|\U0001F441(?:\u200D\U0001F5E8\uFE0F?|\uFE0F(?:\u200D\U0001F5E8\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F442\U0001F443][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F444\U0001F445]|[\U0001F446-\U0001F450][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F451-\U0001F465]|[\U0001F466\U0001F467][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F468(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?\U0001F468|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED]|\U0001F466(?:\u200D\U0001F466)?|\U0001F467(?:\u200D[\U0001F466\U0001F467])?|[\U0001F468\U0001F469]\u200D(?:\U0001F466(?:\u200D\U0001F466)?|\U0001F467(?:\u200D[\U0001F466\U0001F467])?)|[\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD])|\U0001F3FB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F468[\U0001F3FC-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB\U0001F3FD-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB\U0001F3FC\U0001F3FE\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FD\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F468[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FE]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?)?|\U0001F469(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D)?[\U0001F468\U0001F469]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED]|\U0001F466(?:\u200D\U0001F466)?|\U0001F467(?:\u200D[\U0001F466\U0001F467])?|\U0001F469\u200D(?:\U0001F466(?:\u200D\U0001F466)?|\U0001F467(?:\u200D[\U0001F466\U0001F467])?)|[\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD])|\U0001F3FB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|\U0001F48B\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF])|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FC-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|\U0001F48B\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF])|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB\U0001F3FD-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|\U0001F48B\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF])|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB\U0001F3FC\U0001F3FE\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|\U0001F48B\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF])|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FD\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|\U0001F48B\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF])|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D[\U0001F468\U0001F469][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FE]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?)?|\U0001F46A|[\U0001F46B-\U0001F46D][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F46E(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F46F(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\U0001F470\U0001F471](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F472[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F473(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F474-\U0001F476][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F477(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F478[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F479-\U0001F47B]|\U0001F47C[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F47D-\U0001F480]|[\U0001F481\U0001F482](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F483[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F484|\U0001F485[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F486\U0001F487](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F488-\U0001F48E]|\U0001F48F[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F490|\U0001F491[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F492-\U0001F4A9]|\U0001F4AA[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F4AB-\U0001F4FC]|\U0001F4FD\uFE0F?|[\U0001F4FF-\U0001F53D]|[\U0001F549\U0001F54A]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F54B-\U0001F54E\U0001F550-\U0001F567]|[\U0001F56F\U0001F570\U0001F573]\uFE0F?|\U0001F574[\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F575(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F576-\U0001F579]\uFE0F?|\U0001F57A[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F587\U0001F58A-\U0001F58D]\uFE0F?|\U0001F590[\uFE0F\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F595\U0001F596][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F5A4|[\U0001F5A5\U0001F5A8\U0001F5B1\U0001F5B2\U0001F5BC\U0001F5C2-\U0001F5C4\U0001F5D1-\U0001F5D3\U0001F5DC-\U0001F5DE\U0001F5E1\U0001F5E3\U0001F5E8\U0001F5EF\U0001F5F3\U0001F5FA]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F5FB-\U0001F62D]|\U0001F62E(?:\u200D\U0001F4A8)?|[\U0001F62F-\U0001F634]|\U0001F635(?:\u200D\U0001F4AB)?|\U0001F636(?:\u200D\U0001F32B\uFE0F?)?|[\U0001F637-\U0001F644]|[\U0001F645-\U0001F647](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F648-\U0001F64A]|\U0001F64B(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F64C[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F64D\U0001F64E](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F64F[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F680-\U0001F6A2]|\U0001F6A3(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F6A4-\U0001F6B3]|[\U0001F6B4-\U0001F6B6](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F6B7-\U0001F6BF]|\U0001F6C0[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F6C1-\U0001F6C5]|\U0001F6CB\uFE0F?|\U0001F6CC[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F6CD-\U0001F6CF]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F6D0-\U0001F6D2\U0001F6D5-\U0001F6D7]|[\U0001F6E0-\U0001F6E5\U0001F6E9]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F6EB\U0001F6EC]|[\U0001F6F0\U0001F6F3]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F6F4-\U0001F6FC\U0001F7E0-\U0001F7EB]|\U0001F90C[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F90D\U0001F90E]|\U0001F90F[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F910-\U0001F917]|[\U0001F918-\U0001F91C][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F91D|[\U0001F91E\U0001F91F][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F920-\U0001F925]|\U0001F926(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F927-\U0001F92F]|[\U0001F930-\U0001F934][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F935(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F936[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F937-\U0001F939](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F93A|\U0001F93C(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\U0001F93D\U0001F93E](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F93F-\U0001F945\U0001F947-\U0001F976]|\U0001F977[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F978\U0001F97A-\U0001F9B4]|[\U0001F9B5\U0001F9B6][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F9B7|[\U0001F9B8\U0001F9B9](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F9BA|\U0001F9BB[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F9BC-\U0001F9CB]|[\U0001F9CD-\U0001F9CF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F9D0|\U0001F9D1(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F384\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F9D1|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD])|\U0001F3FB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D|)\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FC-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F384\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D|)\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB\U0001F3FD-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F384\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D|)\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB\U0001F3FC\U0001F3FE\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F384\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D|)\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FD\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F384\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?|\U0001F3FF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\U0001F48B\u200D|)\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FE]|[\U0001F33E\U0001F373\U0001F37C\U0001F384\U0001F393\U0001F3A4\U0001F3A8\U0001F3EB\U0001F3ED\U0001F4BB\U0001F4BC\U0001F527\U0001F52C\U0001F680\U0001F692]|\U0001F91D\u200D\U0001F9D1[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]|[\U0001F9AF-\U0001F9B3\U0001F9BC\U0001F9BD]))?)?|[\U0001F9D2\U0001F9D3][\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|\U0001F9D4(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\U0001F9D5[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]?|[\U0001F9D6-\U0001F9DD](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\U0001F9DE\U0001F9DF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\U0001F9E0-\U0001F9FF\U0001FA70-\U0001FA74\U0001FA78-\U0001FA7A\U0001FA80-\U0001FA86\U0001FA90-\U0001FAA8\U0001FAB0-\U0001FAB6\U0001FAC0-\U0001FAC2\U0001FAD0-\U0001FAD6]"
text = "❗foo-foo⚠   9-8 ‍♀foo♀"
print( " ".join([x for x in re.split(fr'\s*({emoji_rx})\s*', text) if x]) )
# -> ❗ foo-foo ⚠  9-8  ‍♀ foo ♀
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/U4f4a0).

The `fr'\s*({emoji_rx})\s*'` part creates a regex that matches zero or more whitespaces, an emoji capturing it into Group 1, and then again zero or more whitespaces. Since the emoji is captured, it is not removed from the resulting list. Since there are consecutive matches, there can be empty matches in the resulting list, so these need removing, hence the list comprehension is used.